# Notification API shows link in Firefox but text in Chrome

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying out the following example for Notifications and the notification works fine and dandy, however , for some reason when I try it on Chrome, the notification contains the following text:

```
<a href="127.0.0.1:8080">127.0.0.1:8080</>
```

But I don't get that on Firefox so I assume it's the default Chrome browser functionality? It looks like this:

[image]

The function:

```
function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
```

Comment: Its really weird but I am guessing thats just to show from what site it was sent. The <a> tags seem to be a bug tho

Comment: it's working fine running it in chrome console inside this website

Comment: So it's a browser issue? I create a basic html and js file so there is absolutely nothing that might be interfering with the notification. What you see is what I have. I'm on Linux using Chrome.

Comment: On Windows 10 [it looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDGSi.png).

Comment: I guess it's a Linux issue, it worked fine on my windows 10 PC too. Still shows the URL but at least it's nicely formatted and doesn't show the anchor tags.